# Erro ao conectar ao banco de dados (mySQL) usando entityFramework

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

Ao tentar conectar no banco de dados recebo esta mensagem:
The underlying provider failed on ConnectionString.

```
<entityFramework>
<defaultConnectionFactory type="MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlConnectionFactory, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6" />
   <providers>
    <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6, Version=6.10.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d"></provider>
                      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
         </providers>
</entityFramework>

<connectionStrings>
    <add name="LattesDatabase" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Entities.Database.LattesDatabase.csdl|res://*/Entities.Database.LattesDatabase.ssdl|res://*/Entities.Database.LattesDatabase.msl; provider = MySql.Data.MySqlClient; provider connection string=&quot; data source = name="*********" ; initial catalog = farol_db; integrated security=False; User id = name= *********; Password = ********; App= entityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Creio que minha string de conexão esteja correta, será que alguém pode me dar alguma luz?

Stack erro:

```
The underlying provider failed on ConnectionString.
   em System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.ChangeConnectionString(String newConnectionString)
   em System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection..ctor(String connectionString)
   em System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.InitializeFromConnectionStringSetting(ConnectionStringSettings appConfigConnection)
   em System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.TryInitializeFromAppConfig(String name, AppConfig config)
   em System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.Initialize()
   em System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.CreateObjectContextFromConnectionModel()
   em System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext()
   em System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.Initialize()
   em System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType)
   em System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize()
   em System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext()
   em System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Linq.IQueryable.get_Provider()
   em System.Linq.Queryable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate)
```

Comment: Olá, seja bem vindo ao Stackoverflow. Brother, se possível coloque na sua postagem a stack completa do erro. Assim fica melhor para ajuda-lo.

Comment: Opa, eu editei ali, se conseguir dar uma olhada, ia me ajudar muito

Comment: Como você montou essa string? deu uma olhada na documentação? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-entityframework60.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sua string de conexão está errada, remova as `"` e substitua os `&quotes` por `'`

```
<entityFramework>
<defaultConnectionFactory type="MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlConnectionFactory, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6" />
   <providers>
    <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6, Version=6.10.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d"></provider>
                      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
         </providers>
</entityFramework>

<connectionStrings>
    <add name="LattesDatabase" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Entities.Database.LattesDatabase.csdl|res://*/Entities.Database.LattesDatabase.ssdl|res://*/Entities.Database.LattesDatabase.msl; provider = MySql.Data.MySqlClient; provider connection string='data source = name=********* ; initial catalog = farol_db; integrated security=False; User id = name= *********; Password = ********; App= entityFramework'" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```